# Output JSON in JavaScript as string with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm having problems outputting JSON string in JS context which could later be used for `JSON.parse()`

This code looks like it should work, but it doesn't, because the resulting string can't be parsed.

(Test the code here: https://3v4l.org/OCW5U)

```
$data = ["Single 'quotes' and double \"quotes\""];

$escaped = json_encode($data, JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT);

echo "var value = JSON.parse('{$escaped}');";
```

Results in:

`var value = JSON.parse('["Single \u0027quotes\u0027 and double \u0022quotes\u0022"]');`

But `JSON.parse()` shows error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token q in JSON at position 30`

Please don't suggest that I don't need to output it as a string.

Any ideas how to handle both quote types and still be able to use `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: Can you clarify why this: `var value = <?= json_encode($data) ?>;` won't do?

Comment: @ChrisG It's pretty interesting: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ff4fgQxPaO0
I can (what I'm doing now), of course, just output raw JSON, but I've been fighting with this too hard - it's basically a matter of principle now... How hard could it be to escape two types of quotes?

Comment: Why are you using `JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT`?  Not sure about JS but PHP decodes it https://3v4l.org/6pk33

Comment: @AbraCadaver Did you look at the outputted JS? It does not encode single quotes and produces invalid JS: `var value = JSON.parse('["Single 'quotes' and double \"quotes\""]');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
https://3v4l.org/lk9a7

```
$data = ["Single 'quotes' and double \"quotes\""];
$escaped_data = json_encode( $data, JSON_HEX_QUOT|JSON_HEX_APOS );
$escaped_data = str_replace("\u0022", "\\\"", $escaped_data );
$escaped_data = str_replace("\u0027", "\\'",  $escaped_data );
echo "var value = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify('{$escaped_data}'));";
```

Result will be:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify('["Single \'quotes\' and double \"quotes\""]'));
```

It working well in my console.

Comment: Does not look like it works if the source text (valid php string) would be: `"Single 'quotes' and double \\\"quotes\""` (add escaped slash `\\\` before before escaped quotes").